# Prolog exercise 2-3-4 tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, prolog

My prof gave me an exercise to do with prolog. Given this goal i have to build the corrispondent 234 tree:

> write(tree(1,tree(11,tree(111,n,n),tree(112,tree(1121,n,n),n)),tree(12,tree(121,n,n),tree(122,n,n),
>   tree(123,n,n),tree(124,tree(1241,n,n),tree(1242,n,n)))))

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Are you asking what is my problem ?

I studied what is a 234 tree, but i dont understand why the tree i represented can be considered a 234 tree, what i see are numbers that range from 1 to 1242. Should a 234 tree be something like this ?

[image]

Comment: Take a closer look at your example tree: The tree term consists of a node id, e.g. 1 at the top, and subtrees. For example: the subtree at node 11, `tree(11,tree(111,n,n),tree(112,tree(1121,n,n),n))`, contains two subtrees, namely those at nodes 111 and 112, while the subtree at node 12 `tree(12,tree(121,n,n),tree(122,n,n), tree(123,n,n),tree(124,tree(1241,n,n),tree(1242,n,n)))`, contains four subtrees, namely those at nodes 121, 122, 123 and 124. A level below, at node 124, there are two subtrees, nodes 1241 and 1242: `tree(124,tree(1241,n,n),tree(1242,n,n))`

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest to keep the subtrees in a list. That would make the term tree more readable because it always has two subterms, namely the node id and the list, and you can use such a term for trees with an arbitrary number of successor nodes, since those are always contained in the list.

Comment: The tree you're showing expressed as a Prolog term appears to have values (1, 11, 12, 111, etc) in it that really represent some kind of node indicies (for illustration purposes) not node values. If they were values, then the tree would not be in proper order, unless your metric for ordering is not strictly numerical.

Comment: Then, why 12 is at the left of 1 and 11 is at its right ?

Comment: The fact is that now i dont understand what is the criteria that produced the 234 tree i showed in the first post.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm talking about. You need to read my prior comment carefully. The numbers in your original representation, 1, 11, 12, 111, etc, do not appear to be in order in the tree. Thus, I do not think they represent node values. They actually seem to represent some kind of node indexing scheme (first level has one digit, second level has 2, etc). Was this structure given as part of an assignment? If so, you need to seek clarification from your instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your given term, pretty printed for clarity:

```erlang
tree(1,      % has 2 child nodes
      tree(11,       % has 2 child nodes
             tree(111,n,n),     % a leaf
             tree(112,          % has 2 child nodes
                     tree(1121,n,n),          % a leaf
                     n)),                     % empty
      tree(12,       % has 4 child nodes
             tree(121,n,n),     % a leaf
             tree(122,n,n),     % a leaf
             tree(123,n,n),     % a leaf
             tree(124,          % has two child nodes
                     tree(1241,n,n),          % a leaf
                     tree(1242,n,n))))        % a leaf
```

It is clear that the "numbers" `1`, `11`, `12`, ..., `1242` aren't used for their numeric value, but just as stand-ins. In other words, the values are unimportant. A valid tree has already been built.

This tree's nodes each have either *2* or *4* child nodes (possibly empty, signified by `n`). That is why it is considered to be a *2-3-4 tree*, where each node is allowed to have *2*, *3*, or *4* child nodes (possibly empty).

Your question then becomes, given a *2-3-4* tree represented by a Prolog compound term like the one above, *print the tree* in the nice visual fashion as shown in your attached image.

This is achieved simply by swapping the printing of nested sub-trees with the printing of the node's value:

```
print_tree( n ).
print_tree( tree(A,B,C) ) :- print_tree(B), 
                             print_node_value(A), 
                             print_tree(C).
print_tree( tree(A,B,C,D) ) :- print_tree(B), 
                             print_node_value(A), 
                             print_tree(C),
                             print_tree(D).
print_tree( tree(A,B,C,D,E) ) :- print_tree(B), 
                             print_tree(C),
                             print_node_value(A), 
                             print_tree(D),
                             print_tree(E).
```

You will have to augment this by passing in the desired indentation level, and incrementing it, by the same amount, when printing the child nodes.